# What is the exact meaning of manifestation?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, science

I am unsure why my professor is using the word **manifestations** for example here

> Biochemical manifestations of apoptosis. Activation of caspase family,
>   DNA and protein breakdown, and Membrane alteration facilitating the
>   recognition by macrophages.

I think the manifestations these *manifestations* are only processes in the apoptosis.
**What is the definition of manifestation?**

**What is a better word for a manifestation?** 
I think just a process.

Comment: Where does one check on the various recognised usages of a word?

Comment: Why don't you think *manifestation* as defined in dictionaries isn't the perfect word?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As you said yourself, from usage! Look up the word in the relevant domain. Of course, one needs to be familiar with the domain to correctly understand the usage in the given context.

Comment: @JonHanna It *is* the perfect word. However, see the comments on this page and you will understand people have difficulty in correctly understanding the implication of the word. A simpler phrase could be better for some readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, the phrase means the way cell-death makes itself appear (presents/ manifests itself) through various means.

Comment: It could just mean the instances / examples in which cell death occurs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No. And in STM/ technical literature, these differences are highly significant. It is difficult to explain here. Think of manifestation as a symptom rather than an example. HTH.

Comment: This is a general English website, and I can find authorities giving say 'instance' as a synonym for 'manifestation'. I'd say the requirement to limit allowable polysemes of 'manifestation' to a scientific register takes this off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I respect your opinion. May be you are right. The given sentence cannot be interpreted using your definition or the synonyms. I suggest you see the meaning of 'synonym' in a dictionary and its usage.

Comment: I've written articles on synonymy / polysemy. No two words are totally interchangeable. Looking at the (English) situation here, I say that 'instance' may replace 'manifestation' in some instances. From the phrasing of OP's opening sentence fragment, the only cue as to which polyseme is intended (unless one attempts a frequency analysis) is the register. Both '(observable) instances' and 'observable results' would fit, unless one has a detailed knowledge of the biochemistry involved (which would take us off-topic).

Answer (score -2):

Would the word transformation better suit the sentence?

Comment: Why would it? It has a completely different meaning.